# What is the execution charset with which Linux is compiled?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, character-encoding

I know that the `-fexec-charset=charset` flag for compiled Linux systems will probably be the default UTF-8. My question is: how do I verify that? Is there some `/proc` variable which will tell me that?

The rationale behind my question is that system calls which take `char *` as a parameter expect the encoding to be in the same format as the compiled kernel. The safest way would be to use the kernel provided variable as a parameter for compiling an application doing system calls.

Note: It's independent of the `locale`, I already checked.

EDIT: Added sample program to illustrate the isssue:

```c
const char * file_name = "/tmp/有難う.txt";

int main(void) {
    if (open(file_name, 0) < 0) {
        perror("failed to open file");
    } else {
        perror("opened file");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```shell
$ touch /tmp/有難う.txt
$ gcc -fexec-charset=UTF-8 source.c && ./a.out
opened file: Success
$ gcc -fexec-charset=UTF-16 source.c && ./a.out
��f: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the subject line directly - that is "What is the execution charset with which Linux is compiled?" - the answer is **any ASCII superset**, where "superset" should be interpreted not just in the setwise sense, but as a coded character set (i.e. all characters in ASCII must be encoded identically to their encoding in ASCII). Other than that, it does not matter, and any choice of `-fexec-charset` should yield binary-identical results.

As for the rest, I think you have multiple misunderstandings going on here. As far as the kernel is concerned there is no such concept as "execution charset" of a process. System calls do not take text in an encoding; they take byte strings.

Pretty much all the option `-fexec-charset` does is tell GCC how to convert `\u` or `\U` escapes that appear in string literals into [sequences of] bytes. If it differs from the source/input charset (`-finput-charset`) then the difference between these two will also govern conversion of unescaped character/string literal contents. It has nothing to do with the locale's encoding at runtime.

C uses the concept of "execution character set" to define the contents of character and string literals as the program sees them at execution time. This is covered in *6.4.4.4 Character constants* and *6.4.5 String literals*.

> With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution character set.

The `-fexec-charset` is part of how GCC defines this "implementation-defined manner".

Since you expanded the question to ask about UTF-16, UTF-16 simply is not a possible character set *in any sense in which C uses the term character set*, so long as the C implementation has a normal 8-bit `char` (which is required by POSIX). This is because C requires members of the basic character set to be present as single-byte characters (precluding a character encoding where all characters are multibyte) and requires that the null byte only represent itself (precluding any character encoding with embedded null bytes). These requirements are specified in *5.2.1.2 Multibyte characters*:

> The source character set may contain multibyte characters, used to represent members of the extended character set. The execution character set may also contain multibyte characters, which need not have the same encoding as for the source character set. For both character sets, the following shall hold:
>
> - The basic character set shall be present and each character shall be encoded as a single byte.
> - The presence, meaning, and representation of any additional members is locale- specific.
> - A multibyte character set may have a state-dependent encoding, wherein each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an initial shift state and enters other locale-specific shift states when specific multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence. While in the initial shift state, all single-byte characters retain their usual interpretation and do not alter the shift state. The interpretation for subsequent bytes in the sequence is a function of the current shift state.
> - A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of shift state. Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character.

It seems to be a bug (or at least "unintentional feature") that GCC allows you to specify `-fexec-charset=UTF-16`. When I tried to do it on the version of GCC I have, attempting to do so produced an internal compiler error and no output. In case your original question was an XY question and you really wanted to know if you could (or why you can't) use UTF-16 as the exec-charset for Linux, the answer is no, and this is why.

Comment: I understand that the kernel takes byte strings, but that does not mean the byte string does not have an encoding. The "execution character set" concept in C is part of C's freestanding specification (OS independent) - So even when compiling the kernel you are specifying an execution charset. So, I guarantee you that if the application and kernel charsets match badly, you will have errors. I do agree with you on the point that this is locale independent.

Comment: @tinkerbeast: Your "guarantee" is incorrect. The interface is purely byte values. There is nothing you can do with `-fexec-charset` that will break application's interaction with kernel, nor anything you can do with it that would affect the way the kernel is built whatsoever. **All this option does** is change how `\u` and `\U` escapes are translated to byte sequences. These escapes do not appear anywhere in the Linux source.

Comment: @r-github-stop-helping-ice I have added a sample program to illustrate the issue. Please let me know your thoughts on this. I believe the fundamental issue here is that you are assuming that byte strings are encoding independent.

Comment: With `-fexec-charset=UTF-16` I get an internal compiler error (ICE): "character 0xa is not unibyte in execution character set" and no output. Apparently GCC allows you to put nonsensical character encodings here (UTF-16 is not a valid choice here from the perspective of the C language) and does, contrary to what I thought and what it used to do, translate from source-charset to exec-charset. However...

Comment: ...the only values for `-fexec-charset` which are valid are those which agree with ASCII at least in the base execution charset (defined in 5.2.1 Character sets ¶3). Among these it does not matter which you pick; it will not change how Linux is built.

Comment: C (unlike C++) does not define a  charset. It defines a bunch of glyphs (but not codepoints or encodings) which the execution and source charset must support. Additionaly for \u esacapes, it demands compatibility with ISO/IEC 10646. So, since UTF-16 supports all the glyphs and I did not use any escape sequences, UTF-16 is perfectly valid within the scope of C. However all this is besides the points since it doesn't answer my original question.

Comment: "C does not define a charset" <-- it defines multiple; see 5.2.1. "UTF-16 is perfectly valid within the scope of C." <-- only if `char` (and thus byte) is 16-bit or larger. Otherwise, per 5.2.1.2, "The basic character set shall be present and each character shall be encoded as a single byte" and "A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of shift state. Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character." These conditions preclude UTF-16.

Comment: Not that this is getting any closer to answering my original question, but - A charset is a glyph to codepoint mapping. C only defines the glyphs, not the codepoints. So it doesn't have a charset. Not sure I follow your logic for the second part. A string literal as defined by the standard is a sequence of 0 or more multi-byte characters of type char. So no restrictions on char * pointing to a multi-byte sequence (which should be obvious from the code running int UTF-8) (See 6.4.5.2 and 6.4.5.5).

Comment: ... So when it says each char is encoded as a single byte, it means a single byte of a multi-byte character. As for \0 it would be \u0000 in UTF-16. Now, dropping utf-16, I just need to find a 8-bit charset encoding which is incompatible with UTF-8. That will have the same effect. The execution charset of kernel and application will not match and we will run into an error.

Comment: @tinkerbeast: You're using terms (especially "glyph") in ways highly mismatched with common usage, but that doesn't seem to be the core issue here. Indeed, if you used `-fexec-charset=ibm1047` or some other EBCDIC charset, or even one of the old ISO-646 variants (the motivation for why IRC treats `{` as "lowercase `[`" :-) you could probably cause Linux to be miscompiled.